# Ingress support for websocket

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, websocket, jetty, kubernetes-ingress

I have a `jetty` web app running under `k8s`. This web app has a websocket end point. The service deployed is exposed via an `nginx` ingress on `https`.

Everything works fine, I have the web app running and the websockets work fine (ie messages get pushed and received) but the websockets close with a `1006` error code, which to be honest doesn't stop my code from working but doesn't look good either.

The websocket is exposed @ `/notifications`. In a "normal" config, ie not `k8s`, just plain software installed on a VM, I would need to add the following to `nginx.conf`

```
location /notifications {
   proxy_pass http://XXX/notifications;
   proxy_read_timeout 3700s;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
   proxy_set_header Origin '';
}
```

I tried doing this via the ingress

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |

```
  location /notifications {
    proxy_pass http://webapp:8080/notifications;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
```

But it has no effect, ie I checked the `nginx.conf` generated and there is no such block added...

Anybody has had issues like this before? any clue on how to solve the `1006` issue?

Answer (score 2):

### `1006` meaning

As per [RFC-6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-46) `1006` means [`Abnormal Closure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent#Status_codes):

> Used to indicate that a connection was closed abnormally (that is, with no close frame being sent) when a status code is expected.

Also see [CloseReason.CloseCodes (Java(TM) EE 7 Specification APIs)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/CloseReason.CloseCodes.html#CLOSED_ABNORMALLY)

There are so many possible causes either on server or on client.

### Client errors: try [websocket.org `Echo Test`](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html)

To isolate and debug client's errors, you may use [websocket.org Echo Test](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html)

### As for server error

#### Jetty

Jetty-related discussion is here: [Question regarding abnormal · Issue #604 · eclipse/jetty.project](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/604). But it doesn't contain any solutions.

#### Race detector for `golang` server code

If your server is written on `golang`, you may try [Data Race Detector - The Go Programming Language](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html)

> Data races are among the most common and hardest to debug types of bugs in concurrent systems. A data race occurs when two goroutines access the same variable concurrently and at least one of the accesses is a write. See the [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem/) for details.
>
> Here is an example of a data race that can lead to crashes and memory corruption:
>
> ```
> func main() {
>   c := make(chan bool)
>   m := make(map\[string\]string)
>   go func() {
>       m\["1"\] = "a" // First conflicting access.
>       c &lt;- true
>   }()
>   m\["2"\] = "b" // Second conflicting access.
>   &lt;-c
>   for k, v := range m {
>       fmt.Println(k, v)
>   }
> }
> ```

#### Case for `PHP` code

The case for `PHP` code discussed here: [Unclean a closed connection by close() websocket's method (1006) · Issue #236 · walkor/Workerman](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman/issues/236)